# hide elements when you click on the body html

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this code, everything works fine, I want to make all elements # content1, # content2 .. hidden when clicked on body. I tried setting for body with z-index smaller than for div while it did not help

```js
    $(function() {
          $('#div1').click(function() {
            $('#content1, #content2, #content3').hide();
            $('#content1').show();
            /* other code ..*/
          });

          $('#div2').click(function() {
            $('#content1, #content2, #content3').hide();
            $('#content2').show();
            /* other code ..*/
          });
    });
```

```css
 html,body{width:100%;height:100%;}

    #div1, #div2, #div3{
           overflow:hidden;
           float:left;
           width:40px;
           height:40px;
           background:red;
           margin:0 10px 0 0;
         }
         #content1, #content2, #content3{
         overflow:hidden;
         position:absolute;
         top:50px;
         background-color:#000;
         color:#fff;
         padding:2px 4px;
    }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <div id="div1">
          <div id="content1" style="display: none;">
            text1
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="div2">
          <div id="content2" style="display: none;">
            text2
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="div3">
          <div id="content3" style="display: none;">
            text3
          </div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The problem you have here is that if the content of the `div` is hidden, then you won't be able to click it to make them visible again

Comment: Also note that I changed your title and description of the problem. `Turn off` and `disable` are very different to the hide/show logic that your code is using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```js
$(function() {
    var div1 = $("#div1");
    var div2 = $("#div2");
    var div3 = $("#div3");
    $("body").on("click", function (e) {
        if (div1.has(e.target).length || e.target == div1[0])
            return;
        else if (div2.has(e.target).length || e.target == div2[0])
            return;
        else if (div3.has(e.target).length || e.target == div3[0])
            return;
        $('#content1, #content2, #content3').hide();
    });
});
```

```css
html,body{width:100%;height:100%;}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
    <div id="content1">
     text1
    </div>
</div>
<div id="div2">
    <div id="content2">
     text2
    </div>
</div>
<div id="div3">
    <div id="content3">
     text3
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I tried when I click on each element including the # div1 elements are hiding, I only want to click on the body

Comment: Try this: `$(function() {
    var div1 = $("#div1");
    var div2 = $("#div2");
    var div3 = $("#div3");
    $("body").on("click", function (e) {
        if (div1.has(e.target).length || e.target == div1[0])
            return;
        else if (div2.has(e.target).length || e.target == div2[0])
            return;
        else if (div3.has(e.target).length || e.target == div3[0])
            return;
        $('#content1, #content2, #content3').hide();
    });
})
`

Answer (score 0):

Your code and what you say are two different things. So:

1. If you just want to hide all the `#content` elements when you click on the `body`, follow Jessika's answer.
2. If you want to hide all the `#content` elements, except for the `#content` element you click (i.e. when you click on `#content1`, you want to hide `#content2` and `#content3`), you can simply do something like this:

   ```
   $(function() {
       $('#div1').click(function() {
           $('#content2, #content3').hide();
           /* other code ..*/
       });

       $('#div2').click(function() {
           $('#content1, #content3').hide();
           /* other code ..*/
       });

       /* other code */
   });
   ```

   Instead of hiding and showing a content, you can let it unchanged and hide only the others.